# Como puedo obtener un valor de las opciones de un select que comparte mismo id con otros select en la misma vista?

Tags: jquery, django, html-select

Sistema para cargar comisiones: Tengo varios **select** que muestran una lista de usuarios, pero estos select se muestran en la vista si el usuario logueado necesita registrar mas de un usuario en la comisión, los puede agregar dinamicamente, el problema esta en que cuando necesito hacer referencia a determinado select usando jquery o solo javascript, no se como puedo hacer referencia a tel select ya que cuando se muestran en la vista, cada select posee el mismo id="nombre", hice una funcion para que cada id tenga un id diferente, ejemplo id="nombrex", x es un numero que se incrementa, pero aun asi sigo sin poder resolver el problema de acceso al determinado select, necesito obtener el valor value="pk" (primary key del usuario que se muetra en la lista) de la opción seleccionada para cargar un numero de afiliado asociado al usuario que se muestra en la lista de opciones mediante ajax en un input.

```
<div class="copy d-none d-print-block"><!--div que se muestra luego de agregar usuario-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="form-row">
     <div id="nombre" class="col-md-6">
       <select id="" name="nombre[]" class="browser-default custom-select">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Apellido y nombre</option>
         {% for afiliado in users %}
         <option value="{{ afiliado.pk }}">
           {{ afiliado.last_name }} {{ afiliado.first_name }}
         </option>
         {% endfor %}
       </select>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-5">
       <input name="num_afiliado[]" type="text" class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Número de afiliado">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
       <span class="float-right mb-3 mr-2">
         <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="text-danger remove">
           <i class="fas fa-user-times fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         </a>
       </span>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Captura para que se entienda mejor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando agrega mas select para registrar mas usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y algo así debería ser la función con jquery o una alternativa

```
$("#nombrex").change(function () {
    ...
});
```

el problema esta en como hago referencia a uno de los selec que se muestran en la vista, o no se si puedo hacer como una lista de los id como pasa con el atributo name y referenciar a tal posición desde el selector de jquery, desde ya si alguien tiene una solución o una propuesta diferente, Gracias!! (desarrollado con DJango, lo cual estoy aprendiendo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener el `id` del `select` y el valor de la opción seleccionada en el evento `change` bien a partir del elemento `select`, o en caso de que tengas más selects, a partir de una clase que sea común a estos elementos select, en el ejemplo he añadido la clase `selname`.

```js
$("select").change(function() {    
    var id = this.id;
    console.log("ELEMENTO: select " + id + " valor seleccionado " +  $("#"+id).val());
});
$(".selname").change(function() {    
    var id = this.id;
    console.log("CLASE: select " + id + " valor seleccionado " +  $("#"+id).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nombre" class="col-md-6">
       <select id="nombre1" name="nombre[]" class="selname browser-default custom-select">
         <option value="" selected>Apellido y nombre</option>
         <option value="1" >Pepe Pérez</option>
         <option value="2" >Mario Gómez</option>
       </select>
     </div>
     <br>
     <div id="nombre" class="col-md-6">
       <select id="nombre2" name="nombre[]" class="selname browser-default custom-select">
         <option value="" selected>Apellido y nombre</option>
         <option value="1" >Pepe Pérez</option>
         <option value="2" >Mario Gómez</option>
       </select>
     </div>
```

Comment: Hola!! buenísimo, ahora lo pruebo, gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Mil gracias!! funciona perfecto, no sabia que así de simple se hacia referencia al elemento seleccionado!!

Comment: No hay de que ;)